# CDK synth for only one stack errors when resources are missing for the other stack

Tags: aws-cdk

My CDK app has two stacks defined, one for a prod environment and one for a dev environment. I have a CloudFront function defined in the stack with a different file path for dev and prod builds (the behavior of the function necessarily needs to be different for dev and prod, i.e. the dev function implements basic authentication so that the dev site will not be publicly accessible and I don't want that code on the prod side). So for example, the CloudFront function is defined as follows:

```js
const cfViewerRequest = new cloudfront.Function(this, "MySite-CFViewerRequest", {
  code: cloudfront.FunctionCode.fromFile({filePath: `backend/functions/cf-viewer-request/build-${props.stage}/index.js`}),
  functionName: `MySite-CFViewerRequest-${props.stage}`,
  comment: `MySite-CFViewerRequest-${props.stage}`
});
```

The idea here is that when the "stage" prop is passed to the stack constructor (it is set to either "dev" or "prod"), the resulting file path for the function will either be "build-dev" or "build-prod". However, if I only build the dev version, I get an error `ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'backend/functions/cf-viewer-request/build-prod/index.js'` when running cdk synth with the dev stack name, since only the dev resource was built. The same goes for other resources, such as the CloudFront deployment, which also has specific dev and prod build directories. How can I run CDK commands for the dev stack without having to build the prod resources beforehand?

Or is there a better way I should be going about this?

Here is the entry point code:

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node
import "source-map-support/register";
import * as cdk from "aws-cdk-lib";
import { MySiteStack } from "../lib/my-site-stack";

const app = new cdk.App();
new MySiteStack(app, "MySiteDev", {
  env: { account: "012345678901", region: "us-east-1" },
  stage: "dev",
});

new MySiteStack(app, "MySiteProd", {
  env: { account: "109876543210", region: "us-east-1" },
  stage: "prod",
});
```

Comment: Try adding the `-e`(exclusively) flag to the synth command: `cdk synth -e MyDevStack`

Comment: @gshpychka I'm still getting the same error even with the "exclusively" flag. I updated my question to include the entry-point code.

Comment: It seems that both of your stacks will have the same name, though, unless that's a typo.

Comment: Not sure if this is the root issue, but I believe `filePath` expects an absolute path: `path.join(__dirname, ...)`.  That would explain the `ENOENT: no such file` error.

Comment: @gshpychka Whoops - that was just a typo here on SO. In my code they are different.

Comment: @fedonev If I build the dev function as well so that both the paths "build-dev" and "build-prod" exist, I don't get the error and it works. My issue is I want to be able to run CDK commands for dev even when prod hasn't been built in my environment.

Answer (score 1):

Typically I would set something like `process.env.NODE_ENV` and then decide which to build based on that

```
new MySiteStack(app, `MySite${process.env.NODE_ENV}`, {
  env: { account: "012345678901", region: "us-east-1" },
  stage: process.env.NODE_ENV,
});
```

Then your build process looks like
`export NODE_ENV=dev`
`cdk synth`
or
`export NODE_ENV=prod`
`cdk synth`

Edit: simplified code and removed if block

Comment: I also tend to expand the cdk.json to include env specific properties and use the `app.node.tryGetContext` to pull them into the root file.

Comment: I gave that a try. It works, but now I notice that if I do a cdk synth for either dev or prod, the other stack disappears from AWS Toolkit developer tools pane in VSCode. Not sure what the ramifications of that are?

Comment: I would assume it's looking at the CF templates in your `cdk.out` directory. Wouldn't worry about it unless it actually integrates with the CF service for the account.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that when I do cdk deploy for one stack it won't delete the other stack?

Comment: Yes, it should be fine. They're in different accounts with no parent stack or pipeline wrapping them. So running cdk deploy with only one or the other "active" should cause it and only it to change.

Comment: Also in the future, I would avoid including your account numbers in code snippets. Not as bad as leaking passwords, but it's still a fairly critical piece of info now available on the internet. Instead do something like
`account: 'account-a'` and `account: 'account-b'`

Comment: Thanks - those are actually dummy account numbers. Look closely 

Comment: what about in a situation where the two stacks are on the same account? Would one get deleted when the other one gets deployed? If so, what's the recommended way of doing it?